# How to hide my source code from inspect element/sources?

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend

I deployed my website on Heroku and I found that the frontend files are all showing under (Inspect Element > Sources). I found that I have to obfuscate my JS files; however, I don't know when, where and how to do the step of the obfuscation.
[image: screen shot]

Comment: You can obfuscate JavaScript (uglify, eval+encode, etc) but you can’t obfuscate HTML.

Comment: Of course they're showing, how else would people be able to visit and use the site? Of you have things you don't want people to see, put them on a server.

Comment: @Dai can you explain more how to deploy the obfuscated JS files. Like I just obfuscate them and replace the unobfuscated with the obfuscated ones then deploy or what?

Comment: Delete the source maps

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev how to delete the source maps

Comment: Wherever you're outputting your javascript, you also have a *.js.map files. Delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the current `"build"` with

```
"build": "react-scripts build && rm build/static/js/*.map && rm build/static/css/*.map"
```

It will remove the js and css from the sources.

Comment: This isn't an answer, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer